# How to invoke repository method for standalone application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I have following repository which extends jpa repositroy and also have an implementation class where i have autowired this.

```
@Repository
public interface ProjectDAO extends CrudRepository<Project, Integer> {}

@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl {

@Autowired private ProjectDAO pDAO;

public void save(Project p) { pDAO.save(p); } }
```

Now i have one `Application.java class`

```
Class Application{
public static void main(String..s){
// I need a way to call a method of repository
}
}
```

configuration file

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories
@PropertySource("file:/Users/abc/Documents/application.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;
```

So how do we call this from main in case i dont to use any web based controller?

Comment: And where is your spring config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way:

```
class Application {
    public static void main(String[] s){
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PersistenceContext.class);
        ProjectDAO dao = applicationContext.getBean(ProjectDAO.class);
    }
}
```

Edit:

```
class Application {
    public static void main(String[] s){
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(PersistenceContext.class);
        ProjectServiceImpl service = applicationContext.getBean(ProjectServiceImpl.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesnt work. Then who do we create serviceimpl class.

Comment: no qualifying bean of type ProjectDAO is defined.But i should get created using spring jpa if it works fine.

Comment: try with `ProjectServiceImpl ` instead, I have this implementation and It works.

Comment: @Malav Perhaps you must to include: `@ComponentScan` and the packages to `@EnableJpaRepositories("your repository package"` in your configuration class.

Comment: I have already added these to configuration class. It didnt work. And proejctServiceImpl also gives same error.

Comment: @Malav even with `ProjectServiceImpl`,  have you the error _no qualifying bean of type ProjectDAO_ ? You must to review your configuration file.

Comment: no It is giving  "no bean name ProjectServiceImpl is defined "

Comment: @Malav check this: https://github.com/dperezcabrera/desktop-app/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/dperezcabrera/desktop/Main.java

Comment: your suggestions were correct, i made very silly mistake at one place. Corrected it. It is working fine. Thanks.